# Custom progress indeterminate horizontal with no corner radius

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a xml file for Custom progress indeterminate horizontal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

with p1 p2 p3 are 3 images in drawable ... but the result look like bellow

http://nu1.upanh.com/b1.s35.d3/00e5e91ffd3e130e92a25b450a125399_53446391.screenshot20130222085912.png

I want indeterminate have no corner radius like image bellow

http://nu0.upanh.com/b3.s34.d4/783c89efa40fa4b95a64b3ca0e9e38a5_53446390.screenshot20130222085920.png

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this: http://mikinw.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/indeterminate-progressbar-with-rounded.html

You can set any shape what you want.